# Using javascript `crypto.subtle` in synchronous function

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptography

In javascript, is it possible to use the browser built-in sha256 hash (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest#Converting_a_digest_to_a_hex_string) inside a synchronous function?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like

```
String.prototype.sha256 = function() {
    // ...
    return hash
}
```

I already tried things like `(async() => {hash = await digestMessage(message); return hash})()`, but I can only get back the promise object.

It seems to me that it might not be possible to achieve what I want, but I thought I'll ask here before giving up. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No, it is not possible to wrap an asynchronous function in a synchronous one in JavaScript *and* propagate the results. Please see this [excellent blog post on sync vs. async functions in various languages](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/). The takeaway is that JavaScript is one (of many languages) in which async functions are infectious due to the nature of how the language runs.

#### Async *built-in* functions are a savior in JS

JavaScript runs on one thread. More concretely, all JavaScript related to a particular webpage runs on the same thread to keep the guarantee that only **one** line of JS will be running in any particular moment. This spares us neanderthal web programmers the responsibility of writing synchronization code like mutexes and atomic operations lest multiple threads write to the same memory simultaneously and cause data corruption or even crashes.

But then, it kind of sucks that we only have one thread to manipulate the visual elements on the webpage *and* run all sorts of business logic like encryption/decryption and data management. That could all get kinda slow and hurt the user experience. But how do async functions fix that? Take this function:

```
function syncGenRSAKey() {
    // fancy math stuff...

    return generatedKey;
}
```

Let's make it async (promise-based):

```
function asyncGenRSAKey() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(syncGenRSAKey());
    });
}
```

Hopefully your intuition doesn't tell you the promise-based function is faster here. All that happens is this:

1. Some code calls `asyncGenRSAKey()`
2. Browser runs `Promise` constructor
3. Promise constructor immediately/synchronously calls the `(resolve, reject) => { ... }` callback function passed to it
4. Browser runs the `syncGenRSAKey()` function
5. The promise fulfills synchronously

**Our code is still completely synchronous. We gained nothing.** Remember, only **one** line of our JavaScript will *ever* run at a time. As long as our underlying key generation code (`syncGenRSAKey()`) is written in JavaScript, it will always eat up time on the main thread no matter where it is called from. That means it will prevent the browser from jumping around to other JavaScript, meaning, event handlers. The browser also renders the page on the main thread so it will freeze almost everything (some CSS animations get rendered specially) on the page while `genRSAKey()` is running. The user can hover a button and neither the button background nor the mouse cursor will update.

Now, please refer back to the subheader for this section of my answer. The key words are *built-in*. Built-in functions, like those provided under `crypto.subtle` are written in whatever language the browser implementers choose: C++, Rust, etc. Those functions are not being run *by* the JavaScript engine, they *are a part of it*. They can spawn up as many OS threads as they want to run on as many (or as few) CPU cores as your computer can spare in a given moment. This means the key generation code could and often will run completely in parallel with a bunch of your JavaScript code and page rendering options, and then the browser will just call back into your JavaScript when the key is ready and any currently running JavaScript is done running, triggering the promise to resolve (or reject if there was an error generating the key), which can then kick off the code in any promises chained onto the key generating one.

> Now, is this really necessary for `SHA-256` checksums in particular? No. In fact I myself still have a GitHub PR I've been putting off because I got tired of *promisifying* everything (which included some very complex Angular components) because I compute *one* f**king hash when the user opens a modal. This aside is for you, Suzanne.

Below are two excellent videos that anyone reading this StackOverflow post should make time to watch. Unless you understand the synchronous/asynchronous nature of JavaScript well enough to picture exactly how your code is going to run, you don't really *know* JavaScript and you will run into bugs eventually that you won't understand.

[The Node.js Event Loop: Not So Single Threaded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zphcsoSJMvM)

[Jake Archibald: In The Loop - JSConf.Asia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)

#### Clarification of `async`/`await` in JavaScript

The `async` and `await` keywords are pure *syntax sugar*. They don't enable you to do anything you previously couldn't using old-fashioned promise chaining, much as promises don't enable you to do anything you couldn't with good ole nested callback functions. `async`/`await` just make your code 10x cleaner. Lastly, promises actually incurred a small amount of runtime overhead vs. using nested callbacks since promises have all sorts of state to facilitate chaining them nicely and are heap-allocated; `async`/`await`, I have heard, may undo that little step-back by making it much easier for the JS engines to see the overall context of the asynchronous code and where variables are used, etc., and make optimizations.

Here are some common examples of `async`/`await` used properly. They are written in TypeScript for clarity of return types but if you just take off the `: Whatever`s it becomes JavaScript.

##### Wrap a synchronous function in promise-based API

This is rarely actually necessary but sometimes you need your code to fit an interface required by 3rd party code like a library.

```
function withoutAsyncAwait(): Promise<number> {
    // Note that the reject callback provided to us by the Promise
    // constructor is rarely useful because the promise will
    // automatically be rejected if our callback throws an error,
    // e.g., if the Math.random() throws an error.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(Math.random()));

    // Could be (ignore the reject callback):
    // return new Promise(resolve => resolve(Math.random()));
}

async function withAsyncAwait(): Promise<number> {
    // If any synchronous code inside an async function throws an
    // error, a promise will still be returned by the async function,
    // but it will be rejected (by far the only desirable behavior).
    // The same is true if an await'ed promise rejects.
    return Math.random();
}
```

You cannot (and why would you) avoid the `Promise` constructor if you are wrapping traditional callback-based
async functions as promises.

```
function timeout(milliseconds: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => window.setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

##### Conditional async step

Sometimes you want to conditionally perform an asynchronous action before a bunch of synchronous code. Before
`async`/`await` this meant you had to duplicate the synchronous code or just wrap it all up in a promise chain
where the initial promise would be a no-op if the condition wasn't true.

```
function doStuffWithoutAsyncAwait1(needToMakeAsyncRequest: boolean): Promise<void> {
    // Might be a no-op promise if we don't need to make a request before sync code
    const promise = needToMakeAsyncRequest ? makeAsyncRequest() : Promise.resolve();

    return promise.then(() => {
        // tons of code omitted here, imagine like 30 lines...
    });
}

function doStuffWithoutAsyncAwait2(needToMakeAsyncRequest: boolean): Promise<void> {
    // Or we can just write the sync code twice, wrapping it in a promise in the branch
    // where we make an async request first. This sucks because our 30 lines of sync
    // code is written twice AND one of the times it is nested/indented inside of both
    // an if-statement and a .then() call
    if (needToMakeAsyncRequest) {
        return makeAsyncRequest().then(() => {
            // tons of code omitted here, imagine like 30 lines...
        });
    }
    
    // tons of code omitted here, imagine like 30 lines...
}

async function cmereAsyncAwaitYouSexyBoiYou(needToMakeAsyncRequest: boolean): Promise<void> {
    if (needToMakeAsyncRequest) {
        // Brings tears to my eyes 
        await makeAsyncRequest();
    }

    // tons of code omitted here, imagine like 30 lines...
}
```

##### Combining async/await and existing promise machinery

`async`/`await` is not a silver bullet. It makes writing a *sequence* of async steps very clean
but sometimes we don't just want a sequence: we want multiple async steps to run at the same time.

```
async function takes12SecondsTotal(): Promise<[string, string]> {
    const result1 = await takes7Seconds();
    const result2 = await takes5Seconds(); // will not get here till 1st result is done

    return [result1, result2];
}

async function takes7SecondsTotal(): Promise<[string, string]> {
    // Both inner functions start doing stuff immediately and we just wait for them
    // both to finish
    const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
        takes7Seconds(),
        takes5Seconds()
    ]);

    return [result1, result2];
}

function nottttttActuallyyyyyTheSammeeeeIKnowIKnowScrewErrorHandling(): Promise<[string, string]> {
    // We are almost there! However, we just introduced a potential sh!tstorm by reducing down our
    // code and getting rid of async/await: we now have the assumption that both the takes7Seconds()
    // and takes5Seconds() calls DO return promises... but they might have synchronous code and the
    // beginning of them that could throw an error because the author screwed up and then they will
    // blow up SYNCHRONOUSLY in our face and this function will also blow up SYNCHRONOUSLY and it
    // will continue up the call stack until it hits a try-catch or it reaches all the way out and
    // the JS engine stops it and logs it in the dev tools
    return Promise.all([
        takes7Seconds(),
        takes5Seconds()
    ]);

    // Let me illustrate:
    function takes5Seconds(): Promise<string> {
        const now = new Date; // Trivia: you don't need constructor parenthesis if no parameters

        if (now.getDay() === 6 && now.getHours() === 21) { // 9pm on a Saturday
            // Synchronous error
            throw Error("I ain't workin' right now, ok?")
        }

        // Returns a promise, whose rejection will be handled by the promise chain, so an
        // "asynchronous" error (but this function could also throw a synchronous error, you
        // never know)
        return doSomeWork();
    }
}

function thisIsFunctionallyTheSame(): Promise<[string, string]> {
    try {
        return Promise.all([
            takes7Seconds(),
            takes5Seconds()
        ]);
    } catch (err) {
        // catch any synchronous error and gift-wrap it in a promise to protect whoever calls
        // us from a synchronous error explosion
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}

async function justBeSmartAndUseAsync(): Promise<[string, string]> {
    // Even though we don't use await at all, async functions act as a stalwart line of defense,
    // stopping any synchronous errors thrown from continuing up the callstack, implicitly
    // catching them and making sure we return a promise NO MATTER WHAT (implicitly does what
    // I did above but the browser probably does it better since async functions are part of the
    // language spec and lots of work has been and will be put into optimizing them)
    return Promise.all([
        takes7Seconds(),
        takes5Seconds()
    ]);
}
```

We might even want multiple sequences of async steps to run at the same time.

```
async function youCouldBeForgivenForDoingThis(): Promise<void> {
    // Please edit this answer if I'm wrong, but last time I checked, an await keyword holds up
    // the entire expression it's part of--in our case, that means the entire Promise.all(...)
    // expression. The doSomethingUnrelated() will not even start running until writeCode()
    // finishes
    await Promise.all([
        pushCodeToGitHub(await writeCode()),
        doSomethingUnrelated()
    ]);
}

async function armedWithEsotericJSKnowledge(): Promise<void> {
    // Also please note I just await the Promise.all to discard the array of undefined's and
    // return void from our async function
    await Promise.all([
        writeCode().then(code => pushCodeToGitHub(code)),
        doSomethingUnrelated()
    ]);
}
```

Never be afraid to store promises in variables, or mix an `async` arrow function into a traditional
`.then()` promise chain as necessary to get the smartest code.

##### The esoteric bullsh*t with returns in async functions

If you use TypeScript or are generally well-acquainted with JS promises, you may already know that
inside of a `.then()` callback, you can return a type `T` **or** a `Promise<T>` and the promise
mechanism internally does the work to make sure just a plain `T` gets passed to the next `.then()`
on the chain. `T` could be `number` or any other type for that matter. `async` functions do the same
thing. Error handling is not as simple.

```
function getNumber(): number {
    return 420;
}

async function getNumberAsync(): Promise<number> {
    return getNumber(); // auto-wrap it in a promise cuz we're an async function
}

async function idkJavaScriptButIWantToMakeSureIGetThatNumber(): Promise<number> {
    return await getNumberAsync(); // this IS fine, really
}

async function iKNOWJavaScript(): Promise<number> {
    return getNumberAsync(); // this will NOT return Promise<Promise<number>> because async unwraps it
}

function iLikeToBlowUpRandomly(): Promise<number> {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        // This is not an async function so this throw clause will NOT get wrapped in a rejected promise
        // and returned pleasantly to the caller
        throw new Error("boom");
    }

    return getNumberAsync();
}

async function iHandleMyProblemsAndAlwaysFulfillMyPromises(): Promise<number> {
    try {
        return iLikeToBlowUpRandomly();
    } catch (err) {
        // This will always catch the "boom" explosions, BUT, if iLikeToBlowUpRandomly() returns a
        // rejected promise, it will sneakily slip through our try-catch because try-catches only
        // catch THROWN errors, and whoever called us will get a bad promise even though we
        // promised (haha) we would only ever return fulfilled promises containing numbers
        return -1;
    }
}

async function iActuallyHandleMyProblemsAndAlwaysFulfillMyPromises(): Promise<number> {
    try {
        // Bam! The normally extraneous await here brings this promise into our pseudo-synchronous
        // async/await code so if it was rejected, it will also trigger our catch branch just like
        // a synchronous error would
        return await iLikeToBlowUpRandomly();
    } catch (err) {
        return 3522047650; // call me if you have job offers  but I'm kinda busy rn and spent way too much time on this
    }
}
```

Comment: Using async crypto in Array.map, Array.filter and ... well... everywhere else is really painful.

Comment: @Ark-kun: using async crypto actually ANYWHERE is nonsensically difficult. Async MAY make sense when you've to wait for external events not under your control (e.g. network) but there's no such a thing when computing sha256 for example. Who came up with this idiocy should be sentenced to coding (and maintain and debug) for the rest of their life by using only async addition, async subtraction, async comparison and asyc variable assignment so they can be "saved" from blocking.

Comment: so basically, a needless pain in the ass when i just want to get a freaking hash during a react render cycle

Answer (score 14):

I agree that an async interface for sha256 is the most stupid thing in the universe (or at least it felt like that when I bounced in this insanity).

My reaction was a [javascript implementation](https://github.com/6502/sha256), probably somewhat slower than what crypto provides, but not doggy slow and with a reasonable interface.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js option (for those who reach this question but not limited to browser):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function sha256(content) {  
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(content).digest('hex')
}

console.log(sha256("test"))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, In your `sync` function you can't directly call your `Promise()`

**Wrong Implement**

```
    const result = utils.digestMessage(data);
```

You must need to use `.then().catch()` approach or `async/await` approach

**Right Implement**

```
const utils = {};

utils.digest = async (data) => {
  try {
    const result = await crypto.digest('SHA-256', data);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};

utils.digest('Neel');

module.exports = utils;
```

Comment: The chance that the an exception is thrown by SHA-256 is of course not that high, but yeah, adhere to best practices. Anything wrong with this answer, GiuppeP? Please comment on, upvote or indeed accept answers.

Comment: This code uses a lot of gratuitous `async/await` for no reason. Instead of having an `async` function like `digestMessage` which just `await`s a single promise, you could just return the promise directly. On that note, the `digestMessage` function is pretty useless as it is a one-liner and detracts from the clarity.

Comment: The `try/catch` is also extraneous. If an error occurs in an `async` function, it will simply reject the generated promise.

Comment: `utils.digest = async data => await crypto.digest("SHA-256", data);`

Comment: Or even `utils.digest = async data => crypto.digest("SHA-256", data);`. No need to await as there's nothing more to do in the same function.

Comment: This is really a terrible API. Thanks for pointing this out, at least I now know that I should stay away from `crypto.subtle` unless I actually need async stuff for other reasons. With this API, if you have a function deep down that needs to use a sha checksum, you need to convert the entire chain of functions to async/await. Quite silly!

Comment: @SamClaus just saw your comments and actually agree with you (had really no experience with js at that time). If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @giuppep I wrote an answer. Actually I felt inspired and wasted a lil too much time on it. Maybe it will help people.

Comment: @SuzanneSoy Yeah the async is kinda extra for SHA hashing since they're so fast. I wish they had a sync version for them. But the async stuff is really good for more intensive things like key generation (see my answer).

Answer (score -3):

What about waiting for the response and use ".then((res)=>{})" after finish. res would contain your desired information

```
promise.then((response) =>{
    const hah = response.data;//I'm not sure about property data. might be different
}
```