# How do I call a JavaScript async function and get a result object, not promise, from it?

Tags: javascript, promise, synchronization

I have some JavaScript code run in browser where I have a very complex object and one of its fields contains a string which I need to replace with a hash of that string. There's SHA-512 implementation built in, but I cannot figure out how to have it invoked synchronously such that execution pauses and waits for the result. I tried this (adapted [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626784/57428)):

```
digestMessage = async (dataString) => {
    let encoder = new TextEncoder();
    let data = encoder.encode(dataString);
    const hash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', data);
    return hash;
};

digest = async (data) => {
    try {
        const result = await digestMessage(data);
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Invocation:

```
myObject.fieldToTransform = digest(myObject.fieldToTransform);
//continue with the object
```

And... sure, it gets me a yet another promise object. Rewriting the invoking code with `.then()` would complicate it greatly. I want the hash, not the promise, so that I pass store that hash and pass it further.

How do I have the hash computed, not promised?

Comment: `await` it if you don't want to use `then`.

Comment: That would require me to put the calling code into `async` and I have no idea what consequences it has on all the surrounding code.

Comment: Thats your only two choices. `then` or `await`. You _can not_ get the result out of a promise synchronously.

Comment: If a function invokes anything asynchronous in order to derive its result, then the function is itself asynchronous and must either return a promise or accept a callback. If you genuinely need to use an asynchronous service for SHA-512, then it is inescapable that callers of `digestMessage()` is asynchronous and callers of the function must be (re)written accordingly.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 A synchronous hash implementation would be just fine but I cannot anything built-in like that.

Comment: Built into what?

Comment: Into anything such that I can use it in browser side JavaScript without carrying extra dependencies.

Comment: Well, since SHA-512 isn't built into Javascript, you have to be be dependent on something.

Comment: I got crypto.subtle.digest() without adding anything, so it looks built-in to me.

Comment: Ah ok, it's something [provided by the browser environment under certain circumstances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto), and made available to Javascript. A bit more built-in than I realised but it depends on definition.